# Moving along a curved path in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to know how can I animate a widget in Flutter along a path like following image:

[image]

Let's say I have a simple curved line:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SamplePath(),
    );
  }
}

class SamplePath extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _SamplePathState();
}

class _SamplePathState extends State<SamplePath> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: CustomPaint( //
          size: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 300),
          painter: MyPainter(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.red
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 8.0;

    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height / 2);
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter old) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

above code generates following result:

[image]

and I want to animate a `Container` or a `CustomePaint` from begin to end of it. How should I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check `PathMetric` class

Comment: so do you have your "curved path" represented by std flutter [Path](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path-class.html) object?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question. God, it's so hard to understand flutter's documentation, for me at least.

Comment: now that you have `Path path` then use `PathMetric`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is the answer to my question. Thanks to `pskink` for mentioning `PathMetric`

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SampleAnimation extends StatefulWidget{

  SampleAnimation();

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SampleAnimationState();
  }
}

class SampleAnimationState extends State<SampleAnimation> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController _controller;
  Animation _animation;
  Path _path;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 5000));
    super.initState();
    _animation = Tween(begin: 0.0,end: 1.0).animate(_controller)
      ..addListener((){
        setState(() {
        });
      });
    _controller.forward();
    _path  = drawPath();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[

          Positioned(
            top: 0,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: PathPainter(_path),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: calculate(_animation.value).dy,
            left: calculate(_animation.value).dx,
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blueAccent,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              width: 10,
                height: 10,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Path drawPath(){
    Size size = Size(300,300);
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height / 2);
    return path;
  }


  Offset calculate(value) {
    PathMetrics pathMetrics = _path.computeMetrics();
    PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.elementAt(0);
    value = pathMetric.length * value;
    Tangent pos = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(value);
    return pos.position;
  }

}


class PathPainter extends CustomPainter {

  Path path;

  PathPainter(this.path);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.3)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 3.0;

    canvas.drawPath(this.path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

[image]

Having some fun!

[image]

**it's time to learn how to draw path!!**

Comment: do not use `Tween(begin: 0.0,end: 500.0)` - simply pass [0..1] value (`_controller.value`) to `calculate()`and multiply it by `PathMetric.length`

Comment: But it seems the ball is not moving along the path at all points

Comment: This work perfectly....but did you notice? widget is not in center of path....how to solve it ?

Comment: @DanielDai, @tailor, I think , `top: dy - (widgetHeight / 2)` and `left: dx - (widgetWidth/2)` can fix it.

Comment: @pskink how we can pass [0..1] any example link?

Comment: @RizwanAhmed check `AnimationController` official docs