# How to locate list of widgets along the curve in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Please tell me, is it possible to locate list of widgets along the curve? [Like on picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTiTE.jpg), Let's say teeth are widgets.

Comment: You can locate them in any way you want but the question is in what format do you have this `"curve"` presented?

Comment: How does the representation of your `"curve"` looks like?

Comment: What kind of object you have that you want to be used to generate flutter layout?

Comment: Some example would be nice

Comment: @Szymon Kowaliński 
Well, for example we have: List<Widget> widgets = [a, b, c, d]; If we want to create row using this list, we can achieve it like this one: 
Row(
children: [ ...widgets],
);
Here widgets will be arranged in a straight line, but what if I want the widgets to be arranged in an arc. Is it possible in Flutter? Is there any widget for such purpose? I wouldn't like to use the stack.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `Stack`, then you might try out the `CustomPaint` widget and drawing in flutter with paths.
There's a tutorial to painting: https://medium.com/flutter-community/paths-in-flutter-a-visual-guide-6c906464dcd0

However, **painting is a limited thing and if you have an actual widgets** that need to be fully responsive and act as a widgets, you need to use `Stack` with `Positioned`. That's the only way to go.

Also, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203515/moving-along-a-curved-path-in-flutter) about animating along the curve in flutter you can find some code examples that use both: painting and stack and even animate that. Possibly the most useful code from there is calculating the position of an object that you want to place along some curve:

```dart
Offset calculate(path, along) {
    PathMetrics pathMetrics = path.computeMetrics();
    PathMetric pathMetric = pathMetrics.elementAt(0);
    along = pathMetric.length * along;
    Tangent pos = pathMetric.getTangentForOffset(along);
    return pos.position;
  }
```

In above example you need to have some `Path` which is a representation of some curve. For example you can get one like this:

```dart
Path getPath(){
    Size size = Size(300,300);
    Path path = Path();
    path.moveTo(0, size.height / 2);
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width / 2, size.height, size.width, size.height / 2);
    return path;
  }
```

then you give this `path` and some `along`, which is number between `0` and `1`, which represents beginning and ending of this curve and you give it to the `calculate`, which return and `Offset`, which you can use in your `Positioned` inside your `Stack`:

```dart
Positioned(
            top: calculate(path, along).dy,
            left: calculate(path, along).dx,
            child: ...
```

When you only want some shapes to be drawn on a screen then you can use simply painting with `CustomPaint` widget, but this objects won't be widgets

Comment: Thank you much for the help!