# Animate container in a curve between 2 offsets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I want to animate my widget in a curve between the two offsets. My current code moves them in a straight line.

```
animation=MyTween(begin: startOffset,end: endOffset).animate(
      CurvedAnimation(
        parent: animationController,
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
      ),);
```

My widget:-

```
AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      child: Container(height:100,width:100, color: Colors.blue),
      builder: (context,child){
        return Transform.translate(
          offset: animation.value,
          child: child,
        );
      },
    )
```

My custom tween:-

```
class MyTween extends Tween<Offset>{
  @override
  Offset lerp(double t) {
    final p = Offset.lerp(begin, end, t)!;
    return Offset(p.dx, p.dy + 100 * sin(2 * pi * t));
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find any difference by changing `curve`?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh they are not meant for moving a widget in a curve path

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203515/moving-along-a-curved-path-in-flutter

Comment: create a custom `Tween<Offset>` class, something like: `class MyTween extends Tween<Offset> { ...` and override its `Offset lerp(double t)` method

Comment: @pskink could you please override and share the code with some dummy values

Comment: it depend on curve, for example: `Offset lerp(double t) {final p = Offset.lerp(begin, end, t)!; return Offset(p.dx, p.dy + 100 * sin(2 * pi * t))}`

Comment: @pksink have used custom tween but it shows begin and end is not defined. Check my updated ques