# How to implement a curved slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

According to image , i have to implement a curved slider like below but i have no idea how to do that with **CustomPainter** and **maths** . i will appreciate if you can help me with that. i tried *sleek_circular_slider* but it give me semi circular slider.

The point is to move the angle across the slider smoothly in the desired slider line

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, a [Curves class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/animation/Curves-class.html) in Flutter allows you to create smooth animations between 2 values, without having to apply Math.

Look behind their code, to understand the math, or simply interact with the Cubic function to create your own specific curves, not just for the animation but the define the position from A to B.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZw8opj38Vo) has useful tricks about Flutter Animation.

You can also look at this answer in Stack Overflow that explains  [Moving along a curved path in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60205853/4605422)

Comment: This doesn't really address the original question. Can you elaborate how animations are related to this problem?

Comment: I've edited my answer. Take a look at the last link I've provided, which answers how to use a path as a reference for animation.